# Resource Ownership evaluation/authorization in an API

Tags: node.js, api, express

I am developing a side project where i was struggling to understand how to authorize the ownership of a resource, that user is trying to edit/delete using an API

Ex: We have three resources

A. Organization **has**
a. Workspaces **has**
1. Projects **has**
(it can have another level)

Let's say a user who is the admin of organization trying to edit the projects, I need to verify if that project belong to his current organization. Traditional way to do this is search through database to find the organization and match the ids. But I want to know if there is any better approach. Organizations like GCP / AWS or any other SAAS based platforms gives flexibility of what a user can edit or which project he can see,  if I wanted this kind of approach, how do i design my db.

I tried looking through online to find a good article or books on this but everybody posting a simple approach of 1:1 relation.

Comment: I have a project which need to limit the other departments from accessing the data of an admin server. I am using role to authorize the route/path/page that one can view/edit. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Not exactly but I have roles which allow users to do certain operation on certain resources. But while they are doing so, I need to know they are doing for their own resources not others.

EX: As an admin of a project in my workspace in my organization, when I hit an API to change something in the project, I should validate if that belongs to the organization I am assigned to.